# Cannot set width of bootstrap popover in angular project

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, popover

There are couple of stackoverflow questions about this subject but none of them worked for me. Maybe this is related somehow with angular4.

Basically I'm just trying to set width of the popover control.

This is the screenshot to understand the issue better.

[image]

```
<a id="searchPopup" data-html="true" data-placement="auto left" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover">
  <span mdTooltip="Search another website worth" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search">
  </span>
</a>

<div id="popover-content" class="hide" style="width: 800px; max-width: 100%;">
  test test test test test test test test test test test test test
  <table style="width:1000px;border:1px;">
    <tr>
      <td>
        test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

  ngOnInit() {

    $('[data-toggle=popover]').popover({
      container: 'body',
      html: true,
      content: function () {
        return $('#popover-content').html();
      }
    });

  }

.popover {
        max-width: 100% !important;
    }

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i thing you need to write that method `afterViewInit` please try that

Comment: I tried this but nothing happens when I click. I imported afterViewInit btw.

Comment: can you create a plunker

Comment: this is interesting, it is working in plunker, so there should be something else in my css or code, https://plnkr.co/edit/c6jkLS5GqKIH3QEifeaC?p=preview

Comment: I have deleted all the other styles from the css files but still same issue

Comment: are you using cli ?

Comment: yes it is an Cli application

Comment: can you try adding all the bootstrap js files to the `scripts` array and css files to `styles` array

Comment: sorry what do you mean with adding scripts array and styles array?

Comment: Ohh my bad, you will have a angular cli. Json file in that there will be a script and styles array add it there, by installing bootstrap using npm

Comment: the markup you posted, is it wrapped inside an other div for wich you set the width?

Comment: No Vega it's not, I've tried moving these code to the top in app component. Rahul I tried still same. I'll create an empty project and try these codes and update here.

Comment: I have created an empty angular4 project and only copied the codes from plunker and still have the same issue. It looks like this is related with Angular4 or CLI configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I have solved this issue.
I just moved the css code from component.css file into styles.css file.
I don't have any idea why it doesn't work in the component css.

```
.popover { max-width: 100% !important;}
```

Comment: It doesn't work in the component styles because the popover has its own encapsulated DOM.